# How to get many latitude/longitude values from a mysql table and place as Google Maps Markers?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a mysql-table with user data inside. Among them there are latitude/longitude position values. (as two separate values) To create a marker out of them this should work:

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(**LATITUDE HERE**,**LONGITUDE HERE**);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: somewhere,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I'd now like to place a single marker for *every* user on a map. How can I get the lat/lng values from the table for all users and finally place all those markers? So basically, how does this loop work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop will work as follows, considering I have an array of users location of following form

```
locations[0] = new Array("latitude" => "lat", "longitude" => "lng");
```

then loop will be as follows

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]["latitude"], locations[i]["longitude"]), map: map});
 }
```